# Why is "intrusive r" not stigmatized like other "mispronunciations"?

Tags: sociolinguistics

Why is it that dropping h's pronouncing (th) as (f), or using a flapped  intervolic t/d are taken as signs of poor education, when it's, objectively, just as orthographically wrong?

Comment: My guess would be, it's a mistake associated with a higher social class. In the US theta-fronting is generally associated with African-American Vernacular, but intrusive R is associated with accents closer to Received Pronunciation. (And flapped T is pretty much universal here so there's no real stigma.)

Comment: All stigmas are social, not rational or linguistic. As such, they're unpredictable and depend on who's speaking, not what they're saying or what it means. Consequently there's no use in looking for objective causes beyond tribal identification.

Comment: I've heard that some teachers *do* stigmatize "intrusive r".  See the second-to-last paragraph of this blog post: http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=2762 Also, where is t-flappping viewed as a sign of poor education? It's ubiquitous in North America in my experience. Did you mean "nt" flapping specifically?

Comment: What has "orthographically wrong" got to do with anything? English orthography is largely non-phonemic, and there are countless dialects that are different in countless ways from whatever your favorite pronunciation is, and if you have a concept of "orthographically wrong", then that would mean they are all wrong except one. Heck, non-rhoticism itself would be "orthographically wrong", and that's part of RP.

Comment: @sumelic I should have been clearer I was in fact referring to -nt- flapping.

Comment: @LjL that is true, there is no one dialect that is "fully right", but some are much closer than others. For instance, the West country and Yorkshire accents are surprisingly conservative, and perhaps the closest to the pronunciation of 16th-century English.  And I know non rhoticism  could be called "wrong", too but I didnt want to possibly offend millions of Brits, Australians, New Zealanders, Nigerians, South Africans, or New Yorkers (trust me you do not want to get on their bad side ;-

Comment: In the late nineteenth century "huntin'" was an aristocratic pronunciation. (And "he don't" was also a high-class expression, though that is not about pronunciation).

Comment: @sumelic What is '-nt' flapping? I thought the usual transformation is '-nt-' -> 'nn' (which is not a flap)

Comment: @Mitch: Supposedly, for at least some speakers the transformation is /nt/ > [ɾ̃] that's a nasalized alveolar flap/tap.

Comment: @Mitch, -nt- -> -nn- doesn't happen, so far as I know, though -nd- -> -nn- does, in some dialects.  David Stampe's analysis is that the -n- nasalizes the preceding vowel, the -n- then disappears (as do all nasal consonants before homorganic voiceless stops), the -t- now is intervocalic and subject to the flapping process, and finally the resulting flap (being a sonorant) is voiced and nasalized.  That leaves a voiced nasal flap from the original phonemic /nt/.  Note that -n- (much less -nn-) is not possible at any stage, though intervocalic phonemic /n/ can also be flapped, ,,, (cont.)

Comment: ... (cont.) resulting in a nasal flap in such words as "manner", "liner", "canner" (which can merge with "canter").

Comment: @GregLee What about 'center', 'printer'? Both those go to 'nn' for me.(It's what I was thinking of)

Comment: @Mitch, If you are talking about the sound itself, I doubt that you have [nn] in "center" or "printer".  If you are talking about spelling, then, perhaps.  "center" and "printer" in my speech are pronounced in the same way that hypothetical words spelled "cenner" and "prinner" would be pronounced.  But although the spelling would have "nn", the sound itself is a nasal flap.

Comment: @GregLee OK about nn really being a nasal flap (but really? how different are a regular n and an alveolar nasal flap either production or perception?)

Comment: @Mitch, nasal stop [n] and nasal flap [ɾ̃] are similar but different.  They can both be spelled the same, "n".  In my speech, nasal flap is a possible pronunciation for words spelled with "n", "nn", "nt", but nasal stop [n] is not a possible pronunciation for words spelled with "nt".  (I have heard [n] here in other American English dialects in words like "printer".)

Answer (score 4):

A pronunciation feature of a dialect is called a mispronunciation only when it is stigmatized.  When it applies to a regular feature of a dialect, like your two examples of r-insertion and flapping, that is simply what "mispronunciation" means -- saying things the wrong, i.e. stigmatized, way.

So if r-insertion and flapping are not stigmatized, they are not mispronunciations.  It is all a matter of terminology and social prejudice.

Your use of the phrase "orthographically wrong" suggests that you have a theory about "correct" pronunciation that all and only the letters used in the conventional spelling of an expression should be directly reflected in pronunciation.  That is an unusual idea, but if you have that prejudice, you do, and it's not the sort of thing that we can argue about.  I don't share it, though.

Answer (score 0):

There is widespread belief that there is single correct way to say things in a language, so if you say tom[ɛj]to and I say tom[ɑ]to then one of us has to be wrong, and furthermore it's you (unless I recognize that my pronunciation tom[ɑ]to is in fact wrong). It's also widely believed that people are taught their language; so if they don't pronounce a word according to an assumed norm, then the most generous interpretation is that they don't know better and that would be because their education was deficient. This applies to r-dropping, r-insertion, θ→f, coda-simplification, use of "ain't", use of "could of" and so on.